# How to make showed div stay unhidden on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a jquery function that on hover it shows a hidden div to the side and it works fine. What I wanted to add is when I hover to the showed div ie `box2` the div disappears therefore I can't interact with box2 how can I make box 2 stay unhidden when I hover on it then on hover out it fades out again. I can do this easily with vanilla javascript but I need the jquery fade effect so how can I accomplish it with jquery. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
$("#box1").hover(function(){
    $("#box2").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#box2").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to handle it. The one that is commented out will keep box 2 visible until you mouse out of box 2.

The other one (uncommented) will set a short timer and test to see if you're still overing over box 2. I think that's the one you're looking for.

```js
let ontarget = false
$("#box1, #box2").hover(function(e) {
    $("#box2").fadeIn("slow");
    ontarget = e.target.id == 'box2'
  },
  function(e) {
    // keep open unless mouse out of box 2
    //if (e.target.id != 'box1') $("#box2").fadeOut();

    // after a short delay (100 ms) test to see if we're still over box2, if so do nothing.
    // though if we mouse out it will rerun this if statement to close it like you expect
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!ontarget || e.target.id == 'box2') $("#box2").fadeOut();
      if (e.target.id == 'box2') ontarget = false
    }, 100)

  });
```

```css
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box1" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box2" id="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Great solution! gonna keep working with it. One question though. when hovering over box 1 multiple times continuously over and over again let us say 8 times then you stop the fading in and out animation plays 8 times but really slow as it should. Is there any way to limit this or a function to control the amount of hover per second to improve the hover experience?@Kinglish

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. First, you could wrap both boxes in a `<div>`, and just modify the jquery code to show the div on hover.

Another option could be to use the css `!important` attribute (it is bad habit, however) to add another style rule to show it. This would look as follows:

```css
.box2:hover {
     display:block;
}
```

Feel free to comment with any questions! Good Luck!

Comment: wrapping both boxes in a single div would mess up the elements CSS that's why am I should control the hover effects through a different div. I don't understand the CSS attribute method you stated though. If I applied on hover effect on ```.box2``` with ```display: block``` the jquery fade-out operation would cancel out the CSS hover attribute. Am I understanding your solution correctly? @Finn_lancaster

Comment: @seriously, the CSS important attribute would override the jquery, which was the whole point of that answer. However, as mentioned, the usage of the css !important is frowned upon